# Unicode Characters in ggplot2 PDF Output

Tags: r, unicode, utf-8, ggplot2

How can I use Unicode characters for labels, titles and similar things in a PDF plot created with ggplot2?

Consider the following example:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data=iris, main="Aʙᴄᴅᴇғɢʜɪᴊᴋʟᴍɴᴏᴘǫʀsᴛᴜᴠᴡxʏᴢ")
ggsave("t.pdf")
```

The title of the plot uses Unicode characters (small caps), which in the output appear as `...`.  The problem occurs only with pdf plots; if I replace the last line with `ggsave("t.png")`, then the output is as expected.

What am I doing wrong?  The R script I have is in UTF-8 encoding.  Some system information:

```
R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

When searching for a solution for this problem, I found some [evidence](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2006-2.pdf) that R uses a single-byte encoding for mutli-byte encodigns such as UTF-8 for PDF or postscript output.  I also found suggestions to, for instance, be able to get the [Euro sign working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706226/plotting-euro-symbol-in-ggplot2), but no general solution.

Comment: `cairo_pdf("t.pdf"); ...; dev.off()` works for me ... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886018/using-unicode-dingbat-like-glyphs-in-r-graphics-across-devices-platforms-e

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As Ben suggested, `cairo_pdf()` is your friend.  It also allows you to embed non-postscript fonts (i.e. TTF/OTF) in the PDF via the `family` argument (crucial if you don't happen to have any postscript fonts that contain the glyphs you want to use). For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
cairo_pdf("example.pdf", family="DejaVu Sans")
qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data=iris, main="Aʙᴄᴅᴇғɢʜɪᴊᴋʟᴍɴᴏᴘǫʀsᴛᴜᴠᴡxʏᴢ")
dev.off()
```

...gives a PDF that looks like this:
[image: ggplot2 graph with custom font family and non-ASCII characters in the title]

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378620/ttf-otf-font-selection-in-r-for-windows-onscreen-vs-pdf); though it doesn't look directly relevant from the title, there is a lot in there about getting fonts to do what you want in R.

**EDIT** per request in comments, here is the windows-specific code:

```
library(ggplot2)
windowsFonts(myCustomWindowsFontName=windowsFont("DejaVu Sans"))
cairo_pdf("example.pdf", family="myCustomWindowsFontName")
qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data=iris, main="Aʙᴄᴅᴇғɢʜɪᴊᴋʟᴍɴᴏᴘǫʀsᴛᴜᴠᴡxʏᴢ")
dev.off()
```

To use the base graphics command `cairo_pdf()` it should suffice to just define your font family with the `windowsFonts()` command first, as shown above.  Of course, make sure you use a font that you actually have on your system, and that actually has all the glyphs that you need.

TThe instructions about DLL files in the comments below are what I had to do to get the `Cairo()` and `CairoPDF()` commands in `library(Cairo)` to work on Windows.  Then:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Cairo)
windowsFonts(myCustomWindowsFontName=windowsFont("DejaVu Sans"))
CairoPDF("example.pdf")
par(family="myCustomWindowsFontName")
qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data=iris, main="Aʙᴄᴅᴇғɢʜɪᴊᴋʟᴍɴᴏᴘǫʀsᴛᴜᴠᴡxʏᴢ")
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me on Linux.  I did not get to work it yet on Windows, neither using the code your provided, nor using `CairoPDF`.

Comment: Getting the Cairo package to work on Windows is tricky.  I wrote up a little tutorial for it [here](https://raw.github.com/drammock/phonR/master/installingCairo.txt).  Does that help?

Comment: To get Cairo library to work on Windows, go to [this page](http://www.gtk.org/download/), click Windows (32/64bit), & under "Required third party dependencies" download the run-time files for zlib, cairo, libpng, fontconfig, freetype, and expat.  Unzip and collect all DLLs and put them in: C:\Program Files\R\R-2.14.0\bin\i386 (or on 64bit systems C:\Program Files\R\R-2.14.0\bin\x64). Also move fonts.conf file from fontconfig zip file into C:\Program Files\R\R-2.14.0\etc\i386\fonts\. On 64bit systems replace "i386" with "x64" in pathnames; also sub 2.14.0 with whatever your version of R is.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it still is not working for me.  I followed all your steps, but when I execute the code from your example above, I still get garbage as a title.  The axis labels work correctly (also when using a different font), just the title that uses the Unicode characters is messed up.  The output is "null device", not sure if that is expected.

Comment: windows-specific code added, drawn from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378620/ttf-otf-font-selection-in-r-for-windows-onscreen-vs-pdf) already mentioned in the original answer. If **that** doesn't work, then probably your version of R was compiled without support for cairo-based graphics.

Comment: Thanks drammock, I appreciate you trying to help to get this working on Windows.  However, the code you posted does not work for me, I still get garbage output in the PDF. No error is shown, except for "null device" mentioned earlier.

Comment: well, assuming you changed "DejaVu Sans" to some other font that you actually have on your windows system, you've exhausted my expertise. FYI, "null device" is not an error, it just tells you which graphical device is the currently active one. "null device" means you have closed the only graphical device that was open.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I really appreciate your help, and for now producing the graphs on Linux works fine for me.  And indeed, I experimented with various fonts that are available on my system, without luck.

Comment: No problem. I made another edit adding the CairoPDF() code, check that against what you've tried just to make sure you didn't miss something small.

Comment: Still does not work, and I get a warning that CairoFonts() does not have an effect on Windows and one should use par(family=..) instead.

Comment: right, sorry, I don't use Windows often and forgot about that issue. I've corrected the answer now, but I'm out of ideas (other than "stick with Linux").

Comment: ... No it isn't anymore; see [my update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64471402/435004).

Comment: cairo is also problematic due to it's poor performance with small font spacing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65188058/font-spacing-whern-using-cairo-pdf-device

Answer (score 9):

As of 2020 and R version 4.0.3, **`cairo_pdf()` is *not* your friend anymore on Mac OS X**, at least as far as Cyrillic is concerned — See Fail Gallery below.

## TL;DR

If you must have Cyrillic, just go back to good ole `png` driver. (And kiss your antialiased diagrams goodbye.)

```
R -e 'png(filename = "ftw.png"); library(ggplot2); qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data=iris, main="Aʙᴄᴅᴇғɢʜɪᴊᴋʟᴍɴᴏᴘǫʀsᴛᴜᴠᴡxʏᴢ"); dev.off()'
open ftw.png
```

[image: What is old, is new again.]

Or if you use [Rmarkdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) with knitr:

```
R -e 'rmarkdown::render("foo.Rmd", "pdf_document", output_file="foo.pdf", runtime = "static", output_options = list(dev = "png"))'
```

## The Fail Gallery

The “modern” approach with Cairo fails in v4.0.3 as demonstrated below. Note that this is not (or not only) a font embedding or rendering problem, since selecting and pasting text out of the generated PDFs also produces garbled output.

Prep steps:

1. [install the latest R](https://blog.theforce.top/2019/06/20/install-r-with-all-capabilities-and-openblas-openmp-on-macos-by-homebrew/) (version 4.0.3 or higher, with all `capabilities()` showing `TRUE`)
2. `R -e 'install.packages(c("Cairo", "ggplot2"), repos="https://cloud.r-project.org")'`

### Vanilla config

```
R -e 'library(ggplot2); qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data=iris, main="Aʙᴄᴅᴇғɢʜɪᴊᴋʟᴍɴᴏᴘǫʀsᴛᴜᴠᴡxʏᴢ"); ggsave("fail1.pdf")'
open fail1.pdf
```

[image: Fail Gallery: vanilla config]

### Using `cairo_pdf()` alone

```
R -e 'cairo_pdf("fail2.pdf"); library(ggplot2); qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data=iris, main="Aʙᴄᴅᴇғɢʜɪᴊᴋʟᴍɴᴏᴘǫʀsᴛᴜᴠᴡxʏᴢ"); dev.off()'
open fail2.pdf
```

[image: Fail Gallery: using cairo_pdf() alone]

### Using `cairo_pdf()` with a custom (supposedly Unicode-compliant) font

```
R -e 'cairo_pdf("fail3.pdf", family = "Arial Unicode MS"); library(ggplot2); qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data=iris, main="Aʙᴄᴅᴇғɢʜɪᴊᴋʟᴍɴᴏᴘǫʀsᴛᴜᴠᴡxʏᴢ"); dev.off()'
open fail3.pdf
```

[image: This is as close as it gets to working with “modern” approaches.]

Another attempt with Comic Sans for good measure:

```
R -e 'cairo_pdf("fail3bis.pdf", family = "Comic Sans MS"); library(ggplot2); qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data=iris, main="Aʙᴄᴅᴇғɢʜɪᴊᴋʟᴍɴᴏᴘǫʀsᴛᴜᴠᴡxʏᴢ"); dev.off()'
open fail3bis.pdf
```

[image: Fail Gallery: using cairo_pdf() with family = "MS Comic Sans"]

### A few more...

With the older "Dark and Stormy Night" version (3.6.2):

```
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/bin/R -e 'cairo_pdf("fail4.pdf", family = "Arial Unicode MS"); library(ggplot2); qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data=iris, main="Aʙᴄᴅᴇғɢʜɪᴊᴋʟᴍɴᴏᴘǫʀsᴛᴜᴠᴡxʏᴢ"); dev.off()'
open fail4.pdf
```

[image]

And with `DejaVu Sans` as suggested by @drammock:

```
R -e 'cairo_pdf("fail5.pdf", family = "DejaVu Sans"); library(ggplot2); qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data=iris, main="Aʙᴄᴅᴇғɢʜɪᴊᴋʟᴍɴᴏᴘǫʀsᴛᴜᴠᴡxʏᴢ"); dev.off()'
open fail5.pdf
```

[image]

DejaVu Sans on older R:

```
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/bin/R -e 'cairo_pdf("fail5bis.pdf", family = "DejaVu Sans"); library(ggplot2); qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data=iris, main="Aʙᴄᴅᴇғɢʜɪᴊᴋʟᴍɴᴏᴘǫʀsᴛᴜᴠᴡxʏᴢ"); dev.off()'
open fail5bis.pdf
```

[image]

Comment: Just because a font is "unicode compliant" doesn't mean it contains glyphs at every single codepoint. Does it fail if you use the font shown in my answer (DejaVu Sans)? Many of the small-cap glyphs in my answer are in the "phonetic extensions" block of unicode which are most likely not present in Comic Sans or Arial MS.

Comment: @drammock DejaVu Sans is the one that comes closest to working indeed (tied with Arial Unicode MS as far as the number of successfully rendered glyphs is concerned). Updated the Fail Gallery.

Comment: strange that it doesn't work even with DejaVu Sans. Page 22 of the DejaVu Sans glyph tables (http://dejavu.sourceforge.net/samples/DejaVuSans.pdf) suggests that it does indeed have glyphs for ᴄ,ᴅ,ᴇ at least, which aren't appearing for you (I didn't check every glyph). Notably, all the failing codepoints are `U+1xxx` while all the successful codepoints are `U+0xxx` so I suspect an encoding problem rather than a font problem.

Comment: I am glad I am not the only one with that problem. Makes me feel less alone

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `ggsave(...)`, you can call `ggsave(..., device=cairo_pdf)`.

You will need to first install  and load the Cairo bindings.

```
install.packages("Cairo")
library(Cairo)
```

Here is a [full example](https://gist.github.com/andrewheiss/ac686b1a057003291e62) (not my work).

Comment: What does the `Cairo` package have to do with `grDevices::cairo_pdf`?