# ggplot format italic annotation

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can I use markup in a ggplot annotation?

Let's say, I have this graph:

```
p <- function(i) 8*i
a <- function(i) 1+4*i*(i-1)

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

i <- 1:(8*365/7)
d <- data.frame(i=i,p=p(i),a=sapply(i,a))
d <- melt(d, id.vars='i')
p <- ggplot(d, aes(i, value, linetype=variable)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept=700^2) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_linetype_manual(values=c(2,1)) +
    #geom_point() +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=(0:20)*365/7, labels=0:20) +
    #scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,700^2), labels=c(0,expression(L^2)))
    scale_y_sqrt() +
    #scale_y_log10() +
    annotate('text', 8*365/7, 1e3, label="P(i)=8i", hjust=1, size=3) +
    annotate('text', 8*365/7, 2.5e5, label="A(i)=1+4i(i-1)", hjust=1, size=3)
print(p + theme_classic())
```

[image: output]

I know I can use *fontface=3* and put everything in italic. But I do not want the numbers in italic, only the variable `i`. Preferably, `P` and `A` would **not** be in italic as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `parse=TRUE` and supply a string formatted according to `?plotmath`.

```
p <- ggplot(d, aes(i, value, linetype=variable)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept=700^2) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_linetype_manual(values=c(2,1)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=(0:20)*365/7, labels=0:20) +
    scale_y_sqrt() +
    annotate('text', 8*365/7, 1e3,
             label="P(italic(i))==8~italic(i)", parse=TRUE,
             hjust=1, size=3) +
    annotate('text', 8*365/7, 2.5e5,
             label="A(italic(i))==1+4~italic(i)(italic(i)-1)", parse=TRUE, 
             hjust=1, size=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 30):

Right now this page is the top search result on google for *ggplot annotate italic*. For the benefit of those who simply want to italicize an entire annotation, I'm writing this post. Use annotate's `fontface` option. Example:

```
seq(0,3.14,0.01)
qplot(x, sin(x)) +   # works the same for qplot or ggplot
annotate(geom = 'text', 
         x = 1.5, 
         y = 0.5, 
         hjust = 0.5,
         label = 'Hello, World', 
         fontface = 'italic')
```

[image]

Comment: FYI, the fontface argument also works with `geom_text`

Answer (score 7):

Best rated answer is just fine, but in a more complex scenario with linebreaks it did not work for me, so I simply used Unicode italic characters instead. For your example:

```
library(Unicode)

italic_i <- u_char_inspect(u_char_from_name("MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL I"))["Char"]
label1 <- paste("P(", italic_i, ")=8", italic_i, sep="")
label2 <- paste("A(", italic_i, ")=1+4", italic_i, "(", italic_i, "-1)", sep="")

i <- 1:(8*365/7)
d <- data.frame(i=i,p=p(i),a=sapply(i,a))
d <- melt(d, id.vars='i')
p <- ggplot(d, aes(i, value, linetype=variable)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=700^2) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c(2,1)) +
  #geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=(0:20)*365/7, labels=0:20) +
  #scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,700^2), labels=c(0,expression(L^2)))
  scale_y_sqrt() +
  #scale_y_log10() +
  annotate('text', 8*365/7, 1e3, label=label1, hjust=1, size=3) +
  annotate('text', 8*365/7, 2.5e5, label=label2, hjust=1, size=3)
print(p + theme_classic())
```

[image: Italic annotation ggplot2]

Edit: I have just noticed that saving a pdf with pdf() doest not render unicode correctly, but you can simply use cairo_pdf() instead, which works just fine (see: [Unicode Characters in ggplot2 PDF Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768176/unicode-characters-in-ggplot2-pdf-output))

Answer (score 3):

**For simple text formatting, use the ggtext package**

If you do not regularly use plotmath, and find it easier to use simple markdown/html style text formatting- use the recently added [ggtext package](https://wilkelab.org/ggtext/)

Adding the reference to the newer `ggtext` package here- even though this example is simpler than the OP question (along the lines of @pbnelson)

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
#> Warning: package 'ggtext' was built under R version 4.0.3
library(tibble)
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 4.0.3
dfx <- tibble(x=seq(0,3.14,0.01))
ggplot(dfx, aes(x, sin(x))) +
  geom_line() + # works the same for qplot or ggplot
    geom_richtext(x = 1.5, 
                  y = 0.5, 
                  label.color = NA,
                  label = "<i><b>Hello</i></b>, World<br>You can even do 
                  Some <span style='color:blue'>blue text **in bold.**</span><br>And *italics text.*"
                  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>