# ggplot2 label: Combination of Greek symbol and exponential term,

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to label my y axis so that it displays first the word "Power" followed by an expression in square brackets: [micro Volt squared].

[image: Power in micro Volt squared]

I can produce single parts of the overall label that I want, but I run into problems when I want to combine them:

```
x <- 1:10; y <- 10:1; z <- data.frame(x,y)
g <- ggplot(z, aes(x,y) + geom_bar(stat='identity')

g + ylab('Power') # No problem
g + ylab(paste('Power [', ']')) #No problem
g + ylab(expression(mu)) # No problem
g + ylab(expression(V^2)) # No problem
```

However, this seems not to be possible:

```
g + ylab(paste('Power [', expression(mu), expression(V^2), ']'))
```

The output does not evalute the expressions (mu and V^2):

[image: ggplot2 Output:Problem y label]

Where am I going wrong? Is the paste() command the wrong approach in general? I have also had a look at unicode characters ([Unicode Characters in ggplot2 PDF Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768176/unicode-characters-in-ggplot2-pdf-output)) ... but that would still leave me with the question how I adequately combine all the single terms.

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put everything inside the expression. 
You can use an asterisk for separation, the tilde is for space. So this should be right.

```
g + ylab(expression("Power"~"["*mu*V^2*"]"))
```

Answer (score 3):

A single `expression` seems to do the trick:

```
g + ylab(expression(paste("Power [",mu, V^2,"]")))
```