# export figures with unicode symbology/expression in R

Tags: r, pdf, export, rstudio

when I export a RStudio generated figure as image it works fine (attached png file)

```
plot(2,3, ylab="cannot export as I see it",
     xlab= expression(paste(delta^{13}, "C (\u2030)")))
```

[image]

but when I try to export the same figure as a pdf, the x-label expression within bracket gets distorted (also attached)!! is there a solution?

```
dev.copy2pdf(file="export.pdf", width = 3, height = 3.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Using `pdf(...);plot(...);dev.off();` (instead of `dev.copy2df`) it looks the same.

Comment: tried that as well ... I am still getting those leveled dots ... is it because I am using a old version of R or something?!?

Comment: Duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768176/unicode-characters-in-ggplot2-pdf-output#12775087 - short answer: install `Cairo` and use `cairo_pdf` driver.

Comment: I'll go with @Spacedman's recommendation. I'm using R-3.5.1 on win10, didn't know about this Cairo bug.